# Font Awesome Icons is not showing in firefox browser but showing in IE,Chrome,safari

Tags: c#, asp.net

Font Awesome Icons is not showing in firefox, but showing in other browsers.

i have included following css.

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="buttons_css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-responsive.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome.min.css" />


<i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i>
```

Comment: Are there any error messages shown in the Firefox browser console?

Comment: no error message showing just icon is not showing. in place of icon, showing rectangle box.

Comment: Are you hosting the fonts?

Comment: yes, on intranet.but it's not showing on local host as well.